# How can I update inner data with specific id in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update the node under promo id between apply and trigger location in firebase. it's not update same location where name already exists. It's disturb the ordering after update the name. I have tried method with`update()` but fail. Then `setWithPrority()` remove my other nodes(apply and trigger) and add only name node after update the name.Note data is already exist in firebase just update the name.

My script:

```
firebase.database().ref('/promotions/v1/' + site + '/'+ promoId).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
  promo_data = snapshot.val();
  if (promo_data != null) {
    var refss = firebase.database().ref('/promotions/v1/' + site + '/'+ promoId );
    refss.child('/').update({"name":promoRuleName});
  }
});
```

My Output!
[image]
Note:
I have not trigger and apply node.I have only promoRuleName string.

Expected Output!

[image].

Please help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want your name data under apply or under promoId ?

Comment: @Gabriel Diez  under promoId But this name should be  between apply and trigger and see second screenshot

Comment: Ok i see what you want but i don't understand why you want to do that..

Comment: @Gabriel Diez i want to see text on original location after update the text .when i update the text my ordering is disturb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is work correctly for ordering between apply and trigger node.try this.

```
    firebase.database().ref('/promotions/v1/' + site + '/'+ promoId).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
            promo_data = snapshot.val();
            if (promo_data != null) {
                var refss = firebase.database().ref('/promotions/v1/' + site + '/'+ promoId + '/');
                // First null the prority of apply node then update name.
                firebase.database().ref('/promotions/v1/' + site + '/'+ promoId + '/'+'apply/').setPriority(null);
                refss.update({'name': promoRuleName});
            }

        });
```

First I null the priority of apply node then update the name using `update()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering you see in the console is based on "priority-then-key". Since you called `setWithPriority()` the natural/alphabetical ordering is disturbed. I highly recommend not calling `setWithPriority()` anymore, the method is a relic from the past before Firebase supported `orderByChild()`.

To fix the problem with your current data, you'll need to delete the priority from the node(s) where you have it. In the sample data you shared that can be accomplished with:

```
firebase.database().ref('/promotions/v1/22516/46/name').setPriority(null);
```

Also see: [What does priority mean in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577915/what-does-priority-mean-in-firebase)

Comment: Please provide proper script to for update data. above script add name at the end of node.
My script does not update firebase:
firebase.database().ref('/promotions/v1/' + site + '/'+ promoId+'/'+'name').setPriority(promoRuleName,5);

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: Don't set priorities; clear them. My code shows how to do that.

Comment: thanks for reply but How to set priority between apply and trigger node please.