# Firebase Priority issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to push the same key for multiple nodes, this key I want to set it's priority to date so when getting the data get recent first,

When I used the key for only one node I do like that

```
Reference.child("ch").push().setvalue(object,0-date.getTime);
```

then when retrieve data get recent

but now when I do this

```
string key=Reference.push().getkey();
```

then

```
Reference.child("ch").child(key).setvalue(object,0-date.getTime);
```

when retrieving with priority order not get the recent 
any help, please!!

Comment: I recommend not using priorities anymore. While they continue to work, they have no benefits and lead to less maintainable code. For more on that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577915/what-does-priority-mean-in-firebase

Comment: Aside from that: since your problem is in retrieving the data, please share the code that reads and processes the data (typically just some `console.log` might be enough to reproduce the problem).

Comment: my problem is I want to get recent first 
so when did the second scenario by getting the key first then set value to this key with priority, when retrieving the data with orderbyPriority not getting recent, I think the second scenario does not push with priority !!