# How to query by value firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I need to delete the media object that has value "-LKJ60LdhSaJOzogSccL". In order to delete it, I have to retrieve its key which was previously generated with childByAutoId function.
How can I query media node by value? I need to query media node in order to get a single child which has a certain value.
This is what I tried and it returns null.

```
 let mediaUID = "-LKJ60LdhSaJOzogSccL"
 userUID = Q6Dm3IMLNLgBH3ny3rv2CMYf47p1

 let refUsers = Database.database().reference().child(users).child(userUID).child("media")
 refUsers.queryEqual(toValue: mediaUID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        print("snapshot.value \(snapshot.value)")
 // prints null
        return
    })


users
   Q6Dm3IMLNLgBH3ny3rv2CMYf47p1
        email: "dondraper@gmail.com"
        fcmToken: "d1I..."

    media
     -LKJ61KoaUUrEt1JtfoS: "-LKJ60LdhSaJOzogSccL"
```

Comment: The only thing I now spot is that you're missing `users` in your database reference: `Database.database().reference().child(userUID).child("media")`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, sorry, I only missed it in my question, but I had it in the original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an instruction to order the child nodes, which means that Firebase (by default) orders and filters on the [priority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31578297/209103) of the nodes. The solution is to order by value and then filter:

```
refUsers.queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: mediaUID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Since you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. You will need to handle that in your code by iterating over the results:

```
for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
   print(child.value)     
}
```

Comment: It works. I understand I need to iterate, though it is a unique object in the database since I get the data as a list.

Comment: If the value is already unique, consider using it as the key. That way you won't need a query, but can just load it by its path: `/users/Q6Dm3IMLNLgBH3ny3rv2CMYf47p1/-LKJ60LdhSaJOzogSccL`.