# difference between exportVal() and val() firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just can't understand What is the difference between exportVal() and val() seem to return the same thing.difference between exportVal() and val() firebase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exportVal()` includes the priority of the node (if it's set) as a `.priority` property in the result.

Priorities are as left-over from a long time ago, and there is no need to use them anymore. So for all intents and purposes `exportVal()` and `val()` should be the same, unless you're writing a tool that may need to handle data that you didn't create yourself (such as backup/restore tools).

Also see: [What does priority mean in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577915/what-does-priority-mean-in-firebase)